# Change body font in moderncv without affecting the other fonts

Tags: fonts, moderncv

Is there a way to change the body font in `moderncv` (v0.7) without affecting the other fonts (for example `\firstnamefont`)?

If I change the font via setting `\sfdefault` it influences not only the body font but all fonts of sections and title in the document.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have some predefined commands to change the fonts of some elements:

`\namefont`
`\titlefont`
`\addressfont`
`\sectionfont`
`\subsectionfont`
`\hintfont`
`\quotefont`

Redefining those commands you can change the font attributes for the associated elements. Here's a little example in which I changed the font associated to the first four commmands to use Zapf Chancery:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{CV}               
\address{Baker Street}{Southampton}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}                         
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}       
\email{john@doe.org}                              
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}            

\renewcommand*\namefont{\fontfamily{pzc}\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont}
\renewcommand*\titlefont{\fontfamily{pzc}\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont}
\renewcommand*\addressfont{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont}
\renewcommand*\sectionfont{\fontfamily{pzc}\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Test Section}
\cventry{2012}{Title}{Institute}{City}{}{Description}
\cventry{2012}{Title}{Institute}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Test Section}
\cventry{2012}{Title}{Institute}{City}{}{Description}
\cventry{2012}{Title}{Institute}{City}{}{Description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to change the font for some particular argument(s) of, for example, the `\cventry` command you can define your own command to include the necessary redefinition(s); here's an example in which I defined a `\Mycventry` command using Zapf Chancery for the last argument of `\cventry`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{CV}               
\address{Baker Street}{Southampton}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}  

\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}       
\email{john@doe.org}                              
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}            

\newcommand\Mycventry[6]{%
  \cventry{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont#6}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Test Section}
\Mycventry{2012}{Title}{Institute}{City}{}{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont \lipsum[2]}
\cventry{2012}{Title}{Institute}{City}{}{\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```

And the output showing the comparison between `\cventry`a and `\Mycventry`:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it is not clear, what I mean by body font. The "body" in your example consists of 4 times the word "Description". So what I want is to change the font of the word "Description" (in a real example the body will be longer) in your example globally without affecting the other font selections. Sorry if that was not clear. Do you know the correct terminology for that, then I will change it in my question.

Comment: @student: Ah, now I see. No, as far as I know, there's not a particular name for that element; a good way to refer to it would be "the sixth mandatory argument of `\cventry`". Please see my updated answer.