# Changing the Font in Moderncv

Tags: fonts, fontspec, moderncv

I'm using the moderncv template and I cannot change the font.

I'm looking at 
https://www.overleaf.com/articles/slash-fontspec-all-the-fonts/qnsxyhrgjsgs
for my fonts. Using \setmainfont does not work.

I'd also like to change section fonts, similar to this solution:
[Change body font in moderncv without affecting the other fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49831/change-body-font-in-moderncv-without-affecting-the-other-fonts), but I don't understand what his \fontfamily{pzc} is doing or how to adapt it for a font from above.

Comment: `pcz` in `\fontfamily{pzc}` is a shorthand for the postscript font [Zapf Chancery](https://ctan.org/pkg/psnfss). You can use the `fontspec` font selection commands in its stead. But in order to help you more, we need to see some code, i.e. a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the solution you linked to (→ [Change body font in moderncv without affecting the other fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49831/change-body-font-in-moderncv-without-affecting-the-other-fonts)), I found that the following works:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FiraSans}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{CV}
\address{Baker Street}{Southampton}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}

\renewcommand*\namefont{\fontspec{FiraSans}\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont}
\renewcommand*\titlefont{\fontspec{FiraSans}\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont}
\renewcommand*\addressfont{\fontspec{FiraSans}\selectfont}
\renewcommand*\sectionfont{\fontspec{FiraSans}\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: This works for me, but not for FiraSans in particular. Not a huge deal, as this does seem to work with most fonts from my list. Thanks!